# How to combine use gradient symbols for layer properties excluding 0?

Tags: qgis, cartography, style

I want to visualize my data by using graduated symbols. 
Now, there are some objects with value "0", they should not be printed on the map (which I solved by using rule-based symbols).
 But, anyway, "0" is included when automatically generating the (equal interval) classes. This is important because my data are values of more or less 1800 to 2000.
Also three different sizes are applied, but I don't think that will be important for this question.

How do I exclude "0", when assigning gradual colours?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the "General" tab and add a query that excludes features with a 0 value. That way, they will not be loaded and won't be used in classification either.

Comment: Works nicely, but has this been "fixed" in any of the latest versions of QGIS, like 2.18? Can we do this already from the "Layer properties > Graduated"?  Thanks!

Comment: @iamgin I don't think so